# Unsupported post request when trying to create a custom audience via the endpoint https://graph.facebook.com/lapi-version), (custom-audience-id/users)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The user with an Id of xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx could not be stored as a Facebook audience member. The call failed to Facebook to save the user ("error":{"message": "Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user changed their password or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.", "type": "DAuthException","code":190, "error_subcode":460, "fbtrace_id"xyz"}}

Need to resolve this issue from production.